# Update está quitando dos item con el mismo código

Tags: php, mysql

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, la idea sería que si en dicha tabla hay dos ítem con el mismo código a pesar de que el campo cantidad sea diferente, que pueda eliminar uno de esos dos ítem, no los 2 al mismo tiempo, pero el problema que estoy teniendo es que la tabla no se actualiza, el código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";

if($codigo){
    include 'conexion.php';
    if($conexion){
        
        $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? limit 1";
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo);
            var_dump($codigo);
        
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            }else{
                $output="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }    
        }else{
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $output="No hay conexion";
    }
}else{
    $output="Codigo vacio o no valido";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

Cabe aclarar que si hago clic en uno de esos item (en app android) el estado cambia a 0, por ende no aparecería en el listado, aqui abajo adjunto captura de pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese código debería funcionar si hay filas coincidentes. Lo único por lo que no funcionaría sería si no encuentra ninguna fila o si la actualización provocara un error de clave duplicada u otro (en cuyo caso el error sería mostrado porque entraría en el `else` que hay luego de `execute`). Otra cosa, para descartar cualquier problema, ¿de qué tipo es la columna `estado`?

Comment: La columna estado es del tipo TINYINT

Comment: Las columnas numéricas deberían recibir sus valores sin comillas, aunque no creo que eso dé problemas, es mejor poner cada tipo de dato como debe ir. Otra cosa (aunque a mi modo de ver es confusa en el MR) es que parece que se le debe poner un `ORDER BY` a este tipo de actualizaciones. Prueba a poner la consulta así: **`$consulta="update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=? order by codigo limit 1";`**

Comment: Y cual sería la idea de agregar el ORDER BY?

Comment: El MR explica algo muy confuso al respecto hablando sobre sintaxis simple y sintaxis múltiple. De todos modos yo he hecho una prueba de concepto basada en tablas INNODB y MYISAM y el código funciona sin problema, actualiza una sola fila, aunque haya una sola coincidente o haya varias. No entiendo por qué no funciona en tu caso, o puede que lo que no funcione sea algún cambio en contenedores de tu código debido a que esos cambios no ocurren de la forma en que esperas, lo cual ya sería otro asunto pero lo que es el UPDATE debería funcionar. ¿Seguro que estás verificando bien los datos?

Comment: @A. Cedano disculpa, pero justamente acabo de probar con esa consulta que tú me dices , pero no me actualiza los registros

Comment: @A.Cedano Los datos los he actualizado con var_dump, pero me retorna el valor correcto, no entiendo en que est'a fallando la consulta

Comment: ¿Si lo haces directamente en la base de datos tampoco los actualiza?

Comment: @A.Cedano en la BD dice "Filas encontradas: 1"

Comment: ¿Qué consulta exactamente dice eso?

Comment: @A.Cedano Esta consulta-> update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=? order by codigo limit 1

Comment: O sea, ¿ejecutas esa consulta directamente en la base de datos (no desde PHP) y te dice : *Filas encontradas: 1*?

Comment: @A.Cedano Exacto, asi es, pero en PHP no lo actualiza, es decir que en PHP dice "Filas actualizadas:0"

Comment: Me extraña que pase, con un `where codigo=?`  ¿Acaso el código es `"?"` ?

Comment: @A.Cedano Cabe aclarar que cuando lo pruebo en la BD la consulta la hago de la siguiente manera: update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=codigo order by codigo limit 1

Comment: ¿O sea si pones por ejemplo `update agregados set estado=0 where codigo='e5' order by codigo limit 1`  sí te actualiza una de las filas?

Comment: @A.Cedano Exacto, dice "Filas encontradas:1" si lo hago directamente sobre la BD

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: a) Escribes la consulta asi, poniendo un marcador también para estado: **`$consulta="update agregados set estado=? where codigo=? limit 1";`** b)Defines una variable para el estado: **`$estado=0;`** c) Pasas también el estado como parámetro: **`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is",$estado,$codigo);`**

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, pero voy a tener formular otra pregunta aparte, porque resulta no es que debo eliminar uno solo si es que hay 2 con el mismo código

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es lo que has indicado en tu consulta:

```
update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=?
```

Esa consulta actualizará todos los registros con el código que pases en parámetro.

Si quieres actualizar solamente una fila, indistintamente, puedes añadir un límite:

```
update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? limit 1
```

O, si quieres actualizar por otro criterio, tendrás que indicar ese criterio:

```
update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? and otraColumna=?
```

Comment: Probé eso de agregarle limite, pero no me acutaliza las filas

Comment: Es decir, el código quedó de la misma manera que lo detallado en mi pregunta, pero la diferencia es que la consulta quedó asi: 
  $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? limit 1";

Comment: @StephanieRM ¿comprobaste que hay filas que coinciden realmente? Si las hay esa consulta actualizaría una de las filas sí o sí, si no lo hace es porque no coinciden o por otro motivo como error en la consulta u otro...

Comment: @A Cedano, ¿Como puedo comprobar si realmente coinciden las filas?

Comment: Una forma de comprobarlo sería imprimiendo una consulta como esta: `SELECT * FROM agregados WHERE codigo = aquiElValorDelCodigo` y ejecutándola directamente en la base de datos. Si te arroja filas habrá datos y si no, significa que no hay datos que cumplan ese WHERE.

Comment: probé eso de ejecutar SELECT * FROM agregados WHERE codigo = aquiElValorDelCodigo sobre la base de datos, y en este caso probé SELECT * FROM agregados WHERE codigo='e5', y efectivamente hay datos

Comment: El problema está en que cuando lo hago con la consulta update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? limit 1, no se me actualiza el listado

Comment: En cambio si ejecuto esta consulta update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? limit 1, sobre la base de datos, me devuelve una fila, ¿es posible que el problema esté en el código PHP?

Comment: Pero, ¿verificaste que en el contexto de PHP el valor que le pasas es realmente `e5`? Me refiero a esta línea: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo);` haz un `var_dump($codigo);` y verifica si imprime `e5`. Por otra parte, según otras preguntas similares a esta, hablabas de **eliminar**  la fila, no de actualizarla... entonces me pierdo, no sé si quieres eliminar o quieres actualizar ¿?

Comment: Probé eso de hacer var_dump($codigo) y efectivamente devuelve e5, string(2) e5, para ser exactos, porque hay dos item con código e5, y lo que quiero hacer es actualizar, si hago clic en uno de esos item. el estado cambia a 0, y por ende ya no aparece en el listado ¿me explico?

Comment: ¿Y qué estado tienen actualmente ambos registros?

Comment: ambos registros tienen estado 1

Comment: Yo lo que quiero actualmente es actualizar solo uno de ellos, no los 2 al mismo tiempo, ¿eso sería posible?

Comment: El `limit 1` precisamente es para eso, para que actualice solamente uno de los registros, @StephanieRM Si no lo hace deber ser por otros motivos, no por la consulta en sí misma. Sugiero que edites la pregunta poniendo el código actualizado para revisarlo.

Comment: Si tiene dos item con el mismo código no actualiza el registro, pero si hay un solo item con un codigo, ahí si que lo actualiza

Comment: Ok @A.Cedano ¿te refieres a editar la pregunta que hice arriba de todo? ¿O sería hacer una nueva pregunta?

Comment: @StephanieRM me refiero a editar la pregunta, arriba.

Comment: Más arriba acabo de editar la pregunta con los cambios correspondientes, me di cuenta que tenia que hacerle otros cambios, revisa ahora a ver que tal